# WPF Binding default mode

Tags: wpf, binding

in one of my apps I have a code like this:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="27" Margin="5,0,5,0" Maximum="{Binding TabuProgressEnd}" Value="{Binding TabuProgress}" />
```

While I was testing this everything is ok, but when my client opened this under VS and run this code threw an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'TabuProgress' of type 'TSPLib.TabuEngine'.
```

Usually I would think this is some kind of hoax, but I know that the guy has no idea about coding and making the "Mode=OneWay" explicit helped. How is it possible that the default binding mode differs on different machines?

Comment: This sounds like a version issue with the framework. I'm not sure when the default binding mode changed, but it could have been in one of the service packs (or a hotfix). There seems to have been a few of these strange changes over the years, and they are hard to keep track of. What version are you targeting?

Comment: Net Framework 4.0, installed with Visual Studio 2010. I can't be sure, but that may be something new, because my client installed VS Pro trial version like two days ago. Maybe it's with Sp1..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Value` property in `ProgressBar` binds `TwoWay` by default so the exception should occur unless you explicitly set `Mode` to `OneWay`. However I can't explain why it doesn't occur on your machine. I tried using Reflector with .NET versions 4.0, 3.5 and 3.0 and as far as I can tell, the default binding mode hasn't changed in a while.

*If you have Reflector installed, it would be interesting to see what the ValueProperty (inherited from RangeBase) looks like on your machine*

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(RangeBase),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            0.0,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal | 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(RangeBase.OnValueChanged),
            new CoerceValueCallback(RangeBase.ConstrainToRange)),
        new ValidateValueCallback(RangeBase.IsValidDoubleValue));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First of all I've learned that default binding mode can be set in DP metadata - I'll be definitely more careful about that in the future. I've checked the above code on my framework and it also has BindsTwoWayByDefault included. This is strange..