# ProgressBar Value Binding to ReadOnly property

Tags: wpf, binding

I am binding the ProgressBar Value Propetry to readonly property of my ViewModel. This works fine on Win 7 boxes but on Win XP machines, it throws exception.

XAML

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'Progress'
```

From the exception message and [WPF Binding default mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759706/wpf-binding-default-mode) post. The solution seems to be set the binding mode to OneWay.

My questions is what is causing the ProgressBar to set the Value? And why it works on Win 7 and not in XP?

Answer (score 3):

A two-way binding means that the target (`ProgressBar.Value` in this case) should propagate its changes back to the source (the `Progress` property).  This is of course impossible if the source is read-only, so the exception makes sense.  The only binding that makes sense, as you noted, is the one way source-to-target binding.

I have no idea why it would work on Win 7 - although presumably "work" just means it fails silently, rather than actually update a read-only property.

Comment: The ProgressBar Value is only changed by change in source (ViewModel) property change. There is no change in ProgressBar due to any user interaction. Hence I am wondering, why ProgressBar source is being updated.

Comment: @Bhavesh how do you know it's being updated?  Presumably it is no, but there is some kind of a runtime check, that throws an exception since the two-way binding is (in principle) invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to:

```
<ProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Minimum="0.0" Maximum="1.0" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Note the change of `Mode`.

Answer (score 0):

I Know this is old, but if you are binding to a read only property, you want to specify that the binding mode is OneWay, not TwoWay.